# fputs changes are saved but new changes revert previous ones

Tags: c++, fopen, filereader, fputs

I need to read a .txt file, find a string to change it and then save the .txt file again. I want that change to be permanent, meaning if I for example need to change two different things, the first change should remain so. For some reason, when I run the code to make a new change, the previous one is reverted, even though the .txt file actually changed, so for example if I have this in the .txt

Data A=2;
Data B=0;

and run the code to change "Data A" to 5, if I open the .txt again it will read:

Data A=5;
Data B=0;

If I run it again to change "Data B" to 3, if I open the .txt again it will read:

Data A=2;
Data B=3;

which I cannot understand if the file is saved. Why is the .txt saving but the "old values" are rewritten?

```
// Extract text from file
FileReader file("config.txt");
char* text = (char*)malloc(file.size() + 1);
file.read(text, file.size());
text[file.size()] = 0;
std::string str = text;

// Do some changes
std::string newstr = str;
newstr.replace(7,1,"5");
char *newText = new char[newstr.size() + 1];
newstr.copy(newText, newstr.size() + 1);
newText[newstr.size()] = '\0';

// Write to file again
file.close();
FILE* configFile;
configFile = fopen("config.txt", "w");
fputs(newText, configFile);
fclose(configFile);
```

Comment: A `rewind(configFile);` directly after `configFile = fopen("config.txt", "w");` looks somehow useless to me.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] showing *all* the code.

Comment: Why on earth are you using `FILE*` and `malloc()` in a C++ program?

Comment: Its not exactly a c++ program...its written on Haxe and then uses some additional c++ code, with which I have little experience...surely theres a better way to do what I want to do?